# How to transform data for bar graph based on multi choice?

Tags: r

So I'm learning to use R/GGplot, it was simple enough to create a single bar chart but I'm struggling to understand how to properly manipulate the data to get the chart I want.

So I have a basic example data file that looks like this in RStudio:

[image]

[image]

Basically, I wanted to make a bar for each option, which counts the "Yes" options. The Y axis would then be equal to the total number of records, with the scale measured in %.

Here is where I think I went completely wrong:

`data_Q1 <- data.frame(Q1 = c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink"))`

I believe here I might need to remove the "No" level, then rename the "Yes" level to the colour name before I can work with it, but I seem to be greatly misunderstanding how I do this.

I've tried using `droplevels()` and `raw_data$Q1_1[grepl("Yes", raw_data$Q1, ignore.case=T)] <- "Red"` but neither seem to achieve the goal I want.

Here is the code I'm using for the graph:

```
ggplot(
    data_Q1,
    aes(
        x=Q1,
        y=sum(
            complete.cases(raw_data)
        )
    )
)
+geom_bar(
    aes(
        fill=Q1
    ), 
    colour="black",
    stat="identity"
)
+labs(
    title="Colours respondents liked",
    subtitle="Q1. Select all the colours you like",
    caption="source: example data"
)
+ylab("Total completes")
+scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

```html
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139), Q1_1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Q1_2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"
    ), class = "factor"), Q1_3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Q1_4 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Q1_5 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -139L), variable.labels = c(id = "id", 
Q1_1 = "[Red] Q1. Select all the colours you like", Q1_2 = "[Blue] Q1. Select all the colours you like", 
Q1_3 = "[Green] Q1. Select all the colours you like", Q1_4 = "[Yellow] Q1. Select all the colours you like", 
Q1_5 = "[Pink] Q1. Select all the colours you like"), codepage = 65001L, class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you provide some sample of your data (other than a screenshot)? There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. 
Avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images.

Comment: @heck1 Thanks, I've added the output of `dput(<yourData>)` to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I am assuming this is from some survey, so your data is (probably) a bit messy.
An approach with `tidyverse` and transposing (`t()`) would look something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
    df <- raw_data
    df2 <- data.frame(t( df %>% summarise(Q1 = sum(Q1_1=="Yes") / length(complete.cases(df)) ,
                       Q2 = sum(Q1_2=="Yes")  / length(complete.cases(df)),
                       Q3 = sum(Q1_3=="Yes")  / length(complete.cases(df)),
                       Q4 = sum(Q1_4=="Yes")  / length(complete.cases(df)),
                       Q5 = sum(Q1_5=="Yes")  / length(complete.cases(df)),) ))

names(df2) <- ("sum_yes")
df2$q <- rownames(df2)
```

Output of df2:

```
> df2
     sum_yes  q
Q1 0.8417266 Q1
Q2 0.7338129 Q2
Q3 0.7122302 Q3
Q4 0.4820144 Q4
Q5 0.7122302 Q5
>
```

Then, we plot the results:

```
library(ggplot2)

   ggplot(
  df2,
  aes(
    x=q,
    y = sum_yes,
    fill = q
  )
) + 
  geom_bar( 
  colour="black",
  stat="identity"
) + labs(
  title="Colours respondents liked",
  subtitle="Q1. Select all the colours you like",
  caption="source: example data"
) +  ylab("Total completes")+scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink") )
```

[image]

with `scale_fill_manual`, you can just specify what the colors of your results should be. 
If I understood the data correctly, you would need to replace the names (`Q1` to `Q5` ) with the respective colors.

Comment: Thanks @heck1, you were right this data is just downloaded straight from online survey software using an R plugin. I've managed to achieve what I want thanks to your answer :)